# Внешняя валидация данных от сервера с промежуточной авторизацией

Tags: javascript, база-данных, node.js, сервер, валидация

Вопрос был создан для помощи мне, в составлении логики валидации данных, то есть проверка логина или условного ID с паролем на валид, вошёл или не вошёл. Как можно отправлять запрос от сервера, в котором нет доступа к интернет, и если есть, только одностороннее с доступом к POST. Надеюсь на подарок в виде вашего ответа :) P.S. Возможно подключение внешних GSM модулей. Любые идеи на этот счёт тоже принимаю, спасибо.

И еще, если по простому, то у сервера есть только локальный доступ. Подключиться к нему можно только локально.

UPD. 17-01-2021.

Как можно принимать локально ответы: Локальный сервер без интернета - локальный компьютер с интернета - внешний сервис - локальный компьютер с интернетом - локальный сервер без интернета

Comment: Что-то я не понял вообще ничего. В чём связь между валидацией и отправкой запроса? Одностороннее это как?

Comment: @andreymal Вот в этом и вопрос, в чём связь и как можно сделать лучше для проверка Валида указанных ранее данных(в виде ID и пароля). В моём понимании можно было сделать отправку запроса на внешний сервер и получить ответ(200 или 401 к примеру). Насчёт одностороннего интернета - подразумевалось собой передачу данных от сервера на тот же внешний сервер, с возможностью приёма ответа. Плюсом является то, что ответ исходит от мобильного трафика одного из GSM устройств. Или может я вовсе заморачиваюсь, и можно сделать проверку на промежуточном сервере в виде отсеивания данных